# How to change a image for a label in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label, gif

Currently I want to try to wait for a condition say x>5 to occur then when that happens I want to change the image for a label, wait for 10 seconds, then return to the original image but I keep getting different errors.

Mainly, I'm wondering how to change a label's image then change it back.
I want to change my image from a photo to a gif then back to the photo.

How can I accomplish this without errors?

Comment: I was able to change the image effectively but implementing a wait time to revert the image to its previous image is proving difficult.  I want the image to change, wait 10 seconds, then change back but the wait seems to be being called before the first image change occurs.

Comment: Post your code. It doesn't sound like you have an issue with tkinter labels. It sounds like an other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
the_label.configure(image=the_first_image)
the_label.after(5000, lambda: the_label.configure(image=the_second_image))
```

Of course, in practice it's slightly more complicated since you have to create the images, worry about if this code is called twice in less than 5 seconds, etc. But the general idea is the same: use `after` to schedule a command to change it back after a given number of milliseconds.

Note: you don't have to use lambda. You can call a predefined function, or you could use functools.partial. There are plenty of examples here on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware of the label.after function!